# Proof with suprema

Tags: real-analysis

> Given two non-empty upper-bounded sets $A$ and $B$ composed entirely of positive numbers where $\alpha=sup(A)$ and, $\beta=sup(B)$, and $C = \{ab | a \in A, b \in B\}$, prove that $C$ is upper-bounded and that $\alpha \beta = sup(C)$

I'm not sure how would one prove this. I think that since $\alpha \geq a \;\forall \;a\in A$ and $\beta \geq b \;\forall \;b\in B$ then $\alpha \beta \geq ab \;\forall \;a\in A,b\in B$ (which would prove C is upper-bounded) but I'm not sure about that. But even if it's true, I have no clue as to why would $\alpha \beta = sup(C)$. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If C is not upper-bounded then there exists $ab> k$ for every k. Now let $k> \alpha\beta$. Contradiction. No argue that $\alpha\beta$ is the supremum.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that $\alpha \beta$ is an upper bound for $C$ is sound, so you just have to show that it is the least upper bound.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be small enough that $\epsilon < 3\alpha\beta$. By definition, there is an $a \in A$ such that $a+\frac{\epsilon}{3\beta} > \alpha$ and a $b \in B$ such that $b + \frac{\epsilon}{3\alpha} > \beta$. Then $C \ni ab$ satisfies
$$
  \alpha\beta
< \left(a + \frac{\epsilon}{3\beta}\right)\left(b + \frac{\epsilon}{3\alpha}\right)
= ab + \frac{a\epsilon}{3\alpha} + \frac{b\epsilon}{3\beta}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{9\alpha\beta}
< ab + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3}
$$
or $ab + \epsilon > \alpha\beta$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, the result follows.

Comment: Could the downvoter please leave a comment? Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. (I didn't downvote, though) Could you explain me why that would prove that $\alpha \beta$ is the least upper bound?

Comment: Sure! As I say, you showed $\alpha \beta$ is an upper bound. If it weren't the *least* upper bound then you could take the supremum $c^*$ of $C$ and add a small value $\epsilon$ to it and get something still less than $\alpha\beta$. But from what I showed, if $\epsilon = \alpha\beta - c^*$ then $\exists$ $c\in C$ s.t. $c + \alpha\beta -c^* = c+\epsilon > \alpha\beta$, or $c > c^*$. So $c^*$ can't be the supremum, contradiction. Hope that helps!